# My memory stream does not write to the content of the httpResponse a ZIP file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, memorystream

I am trying to write the stream resulting from compressing several files in a ZIP but I can't. The ZIP file does, but when I want to write the resulting stream, the copyto method does nothing and my http request never ends.

I don't know why my logic doesn't work, I hope you can help me please.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> downloadFile3(string filePath, System.Threading.CancellationToken token)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new PushStreamContent(async (streamout, context, transportContext) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                        {
                            var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(filePath);

                            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                            {
                                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                                {
                                    await fileStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        ms.CopyTo(streamout); //THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    streamout.Close();
                }

            }, "application/zip"), 
        };
        
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            Size = new FileInfo(filePath).Length,
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
        };

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: What have you done to try to fix the problem?

Comment: I try change WriteTo to  ms.WriteTo(streamout);
 but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you verified any bytes are actually being written to the file? Check out the [example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry?view=net-5.0#examples) from the docs for how to interact with a ZipArchiveEntry. I don't think your `fileStream` actually has anything inside because the `zipArchive.CreateEntry` is creating an entry relative to the root of the archive.

Comment: Don't do this `catch (Exception ex) {  }` especially in a question where are asking about unexpected results